# Installing blender on linux doesn't respond?

Tags: software-installation, blender

I downloaded an older version of blender (2.76b). I Unpacked the archive, then I ran the Blender executable. I have Linux Mint.

This message appears:

> Unknown file type
>
> The file "blender" has no known programs associated with it.  If you trust the source of this file, and have sufficient permissions, you can mark it executable and launch it.  Or, you can use the Open With dialog to pick a program to associate it with.

I click on **Make executable and run**. Then, nothing happens. It's as if didn't do anything. No error messages or anything!

How can I solve this?

**Edit**
It's the first time to use Linux so here are the details.
I write this in the terminal:

> ./blender

This is the response:

> bash: ./blender: Permission denied

Comment: What happens if you run it from the terminal?

Comment: @JosephSible Thank you for your response. Please, see the edit of the question.

Comment: Where is the blender binary? What's the output of `mount`?

Answer (score 0):

Run `chmod +x blender` from the terminal, and do `ls -l blender` to confirm that it worked. It seems that for some reason, the GUI was unsuccessful in making the file executable. If that succeeds, you should then be able to run it.

Comment: The first code doesn't do anything. The second code gives this response: -rw------- 1 m m 117236176 نوف  3  2015 blender